# Apply default themes style for each specific workspace in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.2

I'm getting started to managing themes in Oracle APEX. I have 2 workspace WP1 and WP2. And I also have 2 theme style "jupiter", "mercury". In workspace WP1 I set main themes style is "jupiter". In workspace WP2 the main themes style is "mercury". My case is when I override application from WP1 to WP2 the themes style will change based on application of WP1. How can I prevent this case.

Hope someone can give me the way to pass this case,
Thanks!

Comment: By override I assume you mean a link between apps? First app is in WP1, second app is in WP2. First app have some kind of link which open second app of WP2. Is this what you're doing in flow?